# Behat\Laravel can't find submit

Tags: php, laravel, behat, mink

I'am trying to test my Laravel app by Behat.
There is a homepage with fields for name, email and "Register" button. I'm trying to press button in behat-test, but I have an error Fatal error: Call to a member function press() on null (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)

My HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <body>
        <form action="/thanks" name="register">
            <p align="center"><font size="4"><b>Please, enter your name and e-mail</b></font></p>
            <p align="center"><input name="name" type="text" value="name"></p>
            <p align="center"><input name="email" type="text" value="e-mail"></p>
            <p align="center"><input name="registerButton" type="submit" value="Register"></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My FeatureContext function:

```
/**
 * @When I press the :submit
 */

public function iPressTheSubmit($submit) {
    $element=$this->getSession()->getPage()->findButton($submit);     
    $element->click();
}
```

Scenario:

```
Scenario: Register Test
Given I am on the homepage
When I press the "registerButton"
Then I should be on "/thanks"
```

Output:

> Scenario: Register Test                    # features/regpage.feature:4
>       Given I am on the homepage               # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
>       When I press the "registerButton" submit # FeatureContext::iPressTheSubmit()
>         Fatal error: Call to a member function press() on null (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)
>       Then I should be on "/thanks"            # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()
>   --- Failed scenarios:
>       features/regpage.feature:4
>      1 scenario (1 failed)
>      3 steps (1 passed, 1 failed, 1 skipped)

behat.yml:
`default:
    extensions:
         Laracasts\Behat:
            # env_path: .env.behat
         Behat\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            base_url: localhost:8000
            laravel: ~`

Comment: Fatal error is because the element is not found and the findButton returns null and you are trying to press on null. use a wait condition to wait for element that throws exception if the element is not found. have you tried $this->getSession()->getPage()->pressButton('yourButton');  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with 2 steps:
 1. Setting APP_KEY parameters in .env and .env.behat files
 2. Fixing FeatureContent file like this:

```
 /**
 * @When I press the :arg1
 */
public function iPressThe($arg1)
{
    $element=$this->getSession()->getPage()->find('named', array('id_or_name', $arg1));
    $element->press();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Behat parse the PHP docblock above your custom FeatureContext methods?

`@When I press the :submit` looks like its using jQuery selector syntax which Behat may not be used-to or using. Have a look at similar examples in the base `FeatureContext` class.